# Llenar tablas con primefaces con lista de arreglos de string

Tags: java, primefaces, netbeans-8.2

tengo una duda o problema en netbeans 8.2 y primefaces 6.0 quiero llenar una tabla a traves de un List<String[]> pero solo me permite llenar a traves de una linea de objetos de la clase usuario que en este caso usuario es una clase entidad conectada por hibernate a la base de datos, ¿que puedo hacer en este caso para poder llenar la tabla a traves del List<String[]>?

`En este codigo de consulta de usuario(es html) he intentado insertar a traves de una lista de String cambiando lo que es value="#{user.getCorreo()} por user[0] pero creo que no lo estoy haciendo correctamente`

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"          
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <title>INICIO ADMINISTRADOR</title>
</h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:include src="barra.xhtml"/>
        <div class="table-container">
            <p:dataTable var="user" value="#{usuarioUI.consultUsuario()}" class="custom-table">
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Correo" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.getCorreo()}" />                    
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Contraseña" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.getContrasena()}" />                    
                </p:column>
    <p:column style="width: 30%;">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Acciones" />
        </f:facet>

    </p:column>                    
            </p:dataTable>
        </div>         
    </h:body>
<style>            
        *{
            text-align: center;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        h1{
            margin-top: 2vw;
            font-family: sans-serif;    
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
        }
        .center{
            float: none;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        div.modificar{
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 60%;
            width: 30%;
            padding: 25px;
            margin: auto;
            background: white;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);                
        }
        .form-control:focus{
            border-color:#007738;
        }
        .btn-success{
            text-shadow: none;
        }
        body{
            background-color: #007738;
        }
        .ui-messages{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        /* Estilos para la tabla */
            .table-container {
                box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); 
            margin: 20px;
        }
        .custom-table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        /* Estilos para las celdas de la tabla */
        .custom-table td, .custom-table th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        /* Estilos para el encabezado de la tabla */
        .custom-table th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        /* Estilos para las filas impares */
        .custom-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }            
</style>
```

`consultUsuario regresa un arreglo List<String[]>`

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import mx.dreamcatchersoftware.entidad.Usuario;
import mx.dreamcatchersoftware.helper.UsuarioHelper;

/**
*
* @author Usuario
 */
@ManagedBean(name = "usuarioUI")
@SessionScoped
public class UsuarioUI {
    private UsuarioHelper usuarioHelper;
private Usuario usuario;

public UsuarioUI() {
    usuarioHelper = new UsuarioHelper();
}
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    usuario= new Usuario();        
}

/*public void insertUsuario() throws IOException{
    Usuario us= new Usuario();
    us = usuarioHelper.insertUsuario(usuario.getCorreo(), usuario.getContrasena(), usuario.getPermiso());
    usuario=us;
}
public void updateUsuario() throws IOException{
    Usuario us= new Usuario();
    us = usuarioHelper.updateUsuario(usuario.getCorreo(), usuario.getContrasena());
    usuario=us;          
}*/
public List consultUsuario() throws IOException {
    List<String[]> us = null;
    us = usuarioHelper.consultUsuarios();
    System.out.println("TIPO: "+us.getClass().getSimpleName());
    return us;
}
/*public void deleteUsuario() throws IOException{
    usuarioHelper.deleteUsuario(usuario.getCorreo());
}*/
    /* getters y setters*/
   /* public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }
    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }  */
}
```

'Esta es la clase helper de mi capa vista que ayuda con la logica del UsuarioUI'

```
package mx.dreamcatchersoftware.helper;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import mx.dreamcatchersoftware.entidad.Usuario;
import mx.dreamcatchersoftware.integracion.ServiceFacadeLocator;

/**
 *
 * @author Usuario
 */
public class UsuarioHelper implements Serializable{
   /* public Usuario insertUsuario(String correo, String contrasena, String permiso){
         return ServiceFacadeLocator.getInstanceFacadeUsuario().insertUsuario(correo, contrasena, permiso);
}
public Usuario updateUsuario(String correo, String contrasena){
    return ServiceFacadeLocator.getInstanceFacadeUsuario().updateUsuario(correo, contrasena);
}*/
public List consultUsuarios(){
    return ServiceFacadeLocator.getInstanceFacadeUsuario().consultUsuarios();
}
/*public void deleteUsuario(String correo){
    ServiceFacadeLocator.getInstanceFacadeUsuario().deleteUsuario(correo);
}*/
}
```

'Tengo algunas partes del codigo tapadas con comentarios debido a que estuve probando distintos metodos pero creo que pueden servir que los deje para que vean que estuve intentando y poder mostrar si algun metodo les parece mas viable o correcto'